# Modeless Dialog in App::InitInstance()

Tags: c++, mfc

My application needs to create some expensive stuff in `InitInstance()`. I want to inform the user about the progress so i decided to create a modeless dialog in the `InitInstance()` method.

My problem is, the dialog is not drawn. It updates just after

```
CStartStopDlg dlg(_T("Start"));
dlg.Create(IDD_START_STOP_DLG);
dlg.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

// expensive stuff

m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();
```

Even when i put a sleep after this lines it updates the dialog. The problem is, the MainFrame uses my created resources, so i can't rearrange this lines.

How to solve this issue?

---

EDIT:
The expensive stuff is connection to cameras, connection to io hardware, connection to databases and creating worker threads. The application object owns all this stuff and the mainframe and its views etc use this. As this stuff is not document related its in the application.

Depending on the ethernet load, it takes different time to connect.

The modal dialog does not need to be responsive. I just want something like the start dialog of adobe reader.

The hint with `UpdateWindow()` was the right direction and i added a call to this function as i updated the status. This solved my issue.

Comment: For the dialog to draw, the Application must yield, And even if you call dlg.UpdateWindow() or what, the dialog won't be responsive to user input while you perform that "expensive stuff". Maybe create the dialog box in a different thread? An alternative implementation would be to instead execute the "expensive stuff" under another thread, scheduled after the app is initialized (eg using a timer); UI elements should be disabled then, until the "expensive stuff" is complete.

Answer (score 3):

`CStartStopDlg dlg(_T("Start"));` creates an [owned](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#owned_windows) dialog, since the *pParentWnd* is implicitly set to `NULL` (see [CDialog::CDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zkyyhxw.aspx)). This dialog is owned by the main application window.

One feature of owned windows is, that they are hidden when their owner is hidden. So until you call `m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);`, your owned dialog won't show up either.

There are a number of ways to work around this.

1. The obvious solution would be to show the main application window immediately. However, this may not be practical (and doesn't solve the issue with blocking the UI thread).
2. Offload costly initialization to a worker thread:
   This is required so that the UI thread can service incoming messages, e.g. as a result of user interaction. You need to implement some sort of communication between the worker thread and your GUI thread. Posting a custom message (`WM_APP + x`) to the main application window is usually sufficient.
3. Postpone the expensive initialization:
   `InitInstance` shouldn't be doing any more than is required to start this instance of the application. Any sort of costly operations should be postponed until a point, where the user can see a UI (and potentially cancel that operation).
   A common approach is to create a one-shot timer for this. Since `WM_TIMER` messages are low-priority, those messages will only arrive after all other messages have been processed, and the application is in an operable state. At this point you can offload your expensive initialization to a worker thread, and display a **modal** dialog, until it is finished.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your “expensive stuff” is compute bound and not allowing the update of any UI thread(s).  These types of problems are typically resolved by utilizing a separate thread to provide the progress feedback.  You may want to have a look at [Using Worker Threads](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/552/Using-Worker-Threads) for some background on using threads to resolve this type of problem.

Comment: *"It sounds like your 'expensive stuff' is compute bound"* - Nothing in the question indicates this, and if it were, it'd be irrelevant anyway. The important detail is, that it's **synchronous**. Throwing about buzzwords to cover up lack of insight isn't going to fly around here, I'm afraid. The remainder of this proposed answer is so nefariously vague, that it deserves the *"This answer is not useful"* vote.

Comment: @IInspectable  while I can respect your opinion, I'm often amazed at how you respond to many people on this site.  At least one person saw my answer as helpful, yet, you seek to denigrate me without knowing the first thing about me.  It's time to look in the mirror and see where that nasty streak comes from.

Comment: I don't know, why you set out to take this on a personal level. I commented on the quality of the answer (and you can discard that **one** up-vote, which is generally a way for the OP to say *"Thanks"*, but doesn't otherwise serve as an indication of quality). This proposed answer starts out with a wrong assumption, and tries to suggest solutions (that only happen to apply by coincidence, if at all). If you are amazed, that I leave a comment as to why I down-vote proposed answers, go ahead and be amazed all you want. I can make an exception for you in the future, though.